# Rules about using that to describe people?

Tags: who-that

Can I say, "He is the only person that I know."?

Are there rules about using that to describe people?

Comment: Relative *that* can only be employed in restrictive clauses, but there is no constrain on its referent.

Comment: Which means that, yes, you can use relative clauses with _that_ instead of _who_ when referring to persons. As long as [the relative clause is restrictive](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/xmasthat.html).